# what i need to study befor programming Chat?

Tags: c#, .net, chat

what do I need to study before programming a windows chat application in C#?? Moreover, can you recommended me books names or tutorials links about this topic??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to understand interprocess communication if you want to make a "chat" application.

Typically, in C#, this is currently handled via [Windows Communication Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082.aspx).  That would be a good place to start.

Comment: first thanks you ,but do you think i need anything other ? or it is enough ?

Comment: Recommendations for learning resources [are off-topic for stackoverflow.com Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). However, this information [could be ok as part of a tag wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214338/997587).

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the specific requirements for your chat program. Is your application going to be web-based (runs in the browser) or will people need to download a program for it to work? Will communication be handled directly from one computer to another (peer-to-peer), or will there be a central server that handles communication? Will there be "chat rooms" where more than two people are chatting together at once? Will chat conversations be encrypted for privacy? Will chat conversations be saved?

Depending on your answers to these questions, you may want to look into:

- Windows Communication Foundation
- Asp.net MVC
- SQL Server
- Entity Framework or LINQ to SQL
- Interprocess communication
- AJAX
- JSONP
- Windows Presentation Foundation or Windows Forms

... and possibly others as well.

> If you don't know where you're going, any road will get you there.  -- The Cheshire Cat